# Colored FIND output?

Tags: bash, find, colors

Is it possible to get colored output from the *find* command? That is, in the path of each found item, directories are blue, executable scripts are green, et cetera? I'm using version 4.4.2 of *GNU findutils*.

Edit - To clarify, each result would be highlighted like this:

```
./path/to/file.sh
  ^    ^  ^
  |    |  L green
   blue
```

(if, for example, executing `find . -type f`).

Comment: I wrote a mostly-find-compatible replacement called `bfs` that has this functionality: https://github.com/tavianator/bfs

Answer (score 12, accepted):

*UPDATE:* I've added a new (different) script... `Ignacio Vazquez-Abrams`  had a point: The question really asks for `executable scripts are green, et cetera`.. okay... you'll find such a (prototype) script at the end of this answer.

---

This first (original) section is about `grc` and `grcat`.

This should work; `grc`...   (as *enzotib* has pointed out.. The package name is `grc` ... The sub-utility used in the example, is `grcat`

```
generic colouriser for everything

generic colouriser, can be used to colourise logfiles,
output of commands, arbitrary text....
configured via regexp's.
```

---

The following example prints

- `./` in magenta
- `bin/cpp/` in cyan
- `bigint` in bold white

I haven't fully sorted out how it handles it config file yet, but this looks like it will do what you want (once you tame it).. eg. for a file with no sub-dir, and the color sequence seems to not be in the same sequence as the expressions.
I assume it is possible (but I'm a bit busy at the moment)...

```
echo "# my config file
regexp=(\./)(.*/)([^/]+)
colours=bold white,magenta,cyan
">$HOME/.grc/findhi

find . -maxdepth 3 -name '*' | grcat findhi
```

---

Here is the new *Ignacio inspired* script :)

This works if you use a single path as the first arg to `find`.
There are *UNTESTED* issues in this script. It is only concept.
One issue is: Symbolic Links... *murky waters*...
As-is, it prints an `ERROR` when it encounters an unknown type (eg. a symbolic link), and then continues processing past that.
Thanks to `enzotib` for the `tput` examples.

```
dircol=$(tput bold ;tput setaf 4)
coloff=$(tput sgr0)

root="$HOME"       # define path here, not in 'find` arg
root="${root:-.}"  # default to '.'
root="${root%/}/"  # add trailing '/'
#
find "$root" -maxdepth 1 -name '*' -printf "%y %P\n" | 
  while read -r line ;do
    case $line in 
       d   ) printf "%s\n" "$dircol$root$coloff";;  
       d\ *) printf "%s\n" "$dircol$root${line:2}$coloff";;  
       f\ *) l="$root${line:2}"
             d="${l%/*}/"
             f="${l##*/}"
             cd -P "$d" 
             printf "%s" "$dircol$d$coloff"  
             ls --color=always -R1 "$f"
             cd - >/dev/null
             ;; 
          *) printf "ERROR - type not yet catered for\n";;  
    esac
  done
```

Comment: You forgot to say you are referring to the `grcat` utility from the `grc` package :) At the beginning I had some difficulties to understand what you're saying.

Comment: I really missed the fact that the OP want a different color for different types of files.

Comment: Wow. Too much work to be worth it for me

Comment: When I try to pipe `find . -name "*$1*" -print` 's output , I get following error message: `ERROR - type not yet catered for`

Comment: `grcat` is the best colorizing tool I've found and I use it a lot, though even that's not perfect. Having a piped command at the end of a pipeline makes command line editing less convenient.

Comment: same problem as @enzotib, i found grc here, is this the correct one https://github.com/garabik/grc/blob/master/INSTALL? maybe edit your answer please to include that info.  it looks too involved to add as a dependency for a file that you will share with multiple systems or other users...

Answer (score 12):

You could use `-exec` to do most of that (my solution doesn't color the directory part differently). If you have `-print` in your `find` command, replace it by `-exec ls --color -d`; if you're using the implicit printing, add that. This assumes your `ls` supports the `--color` option.

```
find . -exec ls --color -d {} \;
```

Comment: I'm not sure who upvoted this, but I don't believe they finished reading the question (not that I'm saying this answer deserves a corresponding downvote though)...

Answer (score 6):

*This does only the two-color highlight for path and filename, not the per-filetype thing of* `ls`*:*

Configure the colors of `grep` output in the right way for matched and unmatched part, and match the filename:

```
$ export GREP_COLORS="sl=0;33;49:ms=1;34;49"
$ find /etc/ -type f | head | grep --color=always '^\|[^/]*$'
```

[image: screen-grep-colored]

You may not want to overwrite the variable `GREP_COLORS`, so set it only for `grep`:

```
$ find /etc/ -type f | head | GREP_COLORS="sl=0;33;49:ms=1;34;49" grep --color=always '^\|[^/]*$'
```

(Definitions trom the deprecated variable `GREP_COLOR` have less priority than those in `GREP_COLORS`)

For the color codes, see `colortest-16` from the package `colortest`,
and section "Set Graphics Rendition" in [ANSI terminal command sequences](http://real-world-systems.com/docs/ANSIcode.html).

Comment: Is it possible to make folders bold and it if is a file keep it as unbold?

Answer (score 2):

Another solution is [`fd`](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd) which is...

> ... a simple, fast and user-friendly alternative to [`find`](https://www.gnu.org/software/findutils/). While it does not aim to support all of `find`'s powerful functionality, it provides sensible (opinionated) defaults for a majority of use cases.
>
> https://github.com/sharkdp/fd

[image: fd demo]

Beside the colorized output it has several nice features:

> - Intuitive syntax: `fd PATTERN` instead of `find -iname '*PATTERN*'`.
> - Regular expression (default) and glob-based patterns.
> - [Very fast](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd#benchmark) due to parallelized directory traversal.
> - Uses colors to highlight different file types (same as `ls`).
> - Supports [parallel command execution](https://github.com/sharkdp/fd#command-execution)
> - Smart case: the search is case-insensitive by default. It switches to case-sensitive if the pattern contains an uppercase character[*](https://vimdoc.sourceforge.net/htmldoc/options.html#%27smartcase%27).
> - Ignores hidden directories and files, by default.
> - Ignores patterns from your `.gitignore`, by default.
> - The command name is 50% shorter[*](https://github.com/ggreer/the_silver_searcher) than `find` :-).

In Debian and derivatives such as Ubuntu at least, it is called `fdfind` (name 75% longer than `find` :-)) because of a name clashing with another package.

Answer (score 0):

I liked the -exec idea. I used it to create this function:

```
ff() {
    find . -name "$1" -exec ls -G -d {} +
}
```

`-G` is for FreeBSD `ls` (also found on Darwin or macos). For GNU or toybox (Android) `ls`, the equivalent is `--color=auto`.

Comment: This doesn't seem to produce color ..?

Answer (score 0):

*Extending on [Peter O.'s answer](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/26325/414211):*

You can add this function definition into your `.bashrc` or `.bash_aliases`.

(`lr` stands for list recursive, but you can name it however you want)

```bsh
lr () { 
   dircol=$(tput bold ;tput setaf 4)
   coloff=$(tput sgr0)


   case $# in
    2)
     root=$2
     depth=$1
     ;;
    1)
     root="."
     depth=$1
     ;;
    0)
     root="."
     depth=2
     ;;   
    *)
     echo "Specify only upto 2 arguments: [depth [root folder]]"
     return
     ;;
   esac

   root="${root%/}/"  # add trailing '/'
   
   find "$root" -maxdepth "$depth" -name '*' -printf "%y %P\n" | 
    while read -r line ; do
       case $line in 
        d   ) printf "%s\n" "$dircol$root$coloff";;  
        d\ *) printf "%s\n" "$dircol$root${line:2}$coloff";;  
        f\ *) l="$root${line:2}"
            d="${l%/*}/"
            f="${l##*/}"
            cd -P "$d" 
            printf "%s" "$dircol$d$coloff"  
            ls --color=always -R1 "$f"
            cd - >/dev/null
            ;; 
        # l\ *) printf "This is link.\n";;
        l\ *) l="$root${line:2}"
            d="${l%/*}/"
            f="${l##*/}"            
            cd -P "$d" 
            printf "%s" "$dircol$d$coloff"  
            ls --color=always -d1 "$f" | tr -d '\n' 
            printf " -> "
            readlink -f "$f"
            cd - >/dev/null
            ;; 
           *) printf "ERROR - type not yet catered for\n";;  
       esac
    done
}
```

This first parses the `location` and `--maxdepth` the `find` will work on, and then lists it with the colors.

It uses the arguments in the form `[depth [root folder]]`

Example uses:

```bsh
lr 
lr 5
lr 2 Documents
```

Answer (score 0):

If it's about colouring the files as `ls` does with `--color` (or `-G` on some BSDs) except for the path components leading to them to be coloured in blue+bold, then you could do:

```
find . -exec ls -q --color -d {} + |
  sed -E $'s|^((\e\[[0-9;]*m)*)(.*/)|\e[1;34m\\3\e[m\\1|'
```

(assuming a shell with support for ksh93-style `$'...'` quotes).

Where `sed` adds the blue+bold escape sequence (`\e[1;34m` .. `\e[m`) to the directory part.