# customise ls color for directories contain specified file/s

Tags: ls, colors, tcsh

How can I colorize directories contain files with word **INCORRECT** inside?

Example:

I have 3 directories which contain log file.

```
dir_a/log
dir_b/log
dir_c/log
```

The file log in dir_c contain word **INCORRECT**
Is it possible to get colorized ls output as following?

```
dir_a --> blue
dir_b --> blue
dir_c --> red
```

Comment: No. If so, `ls` had to read the file first, which slows down directory listing.

Comment: You might find this useful - [Colored Find output](http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26313/colored-find-output)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This should do the job:
"INCORRECT" in text inside of files inside of folders and files within given folder:

```
SEARCH_DIR="/var/log"
for i in $(find $SEARCH_DIR -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1); do 
    DIR_CHECK=$(grep INCORRECT $i) 
    [[ "$DIR_CHECK" =~ "INCORRECT" ]]  \
        && echo -e "\e[00;31m$i\e[00m" \
        || echo -e "\e[00;32m$i\e[00m"
done
```

"INCORRECT in text inside of files inside of folders in the given folder":

```
SEARCH_DIR="/var/log"
for i in $(find $SEARCH_DIR -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d); do 
    DIR_CHECK=$(grep INCORRECT $i)
    [[ "$DIR_CHECK" =~ "INCORRECT" ]]  \
        && echo -e "\e[00;31m$i\e[00m" \
        || echo -e "\e[00;32m$i\e[00m"
done
```

"INCORRECT" in name of folders and files in given folder:

```
SEARCH_DIR="/var/log"
for i in $(find $SEARCH_DIR -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1); do
    DIR_CHECK=$(echo $i | grep INCORRECT)
    [[ "$DIR_CHECK" =~ "INCORRECT" ]]  \
        && echo -e "\e[00;31m$i\e[00m" \
        || echo -e "\e[00;32m$i\e[00m"
done
```

"INCORRECT" in name of folders in given folders:

```
SEARCH_DIR="/var/log"
for i in $(find $SEARCH_DIR -maxdepth 1 -mindepth 1 -type d); do
    DIR_CHECK=$(echo $i | grep INCORRECT)
    [[ "$DIR_CHECK" =~ "INCORRECT" ]]  \
        && echo -e "\e[00;31m$i\e[00m" \
        || echo -e "\e[00;32m$i\e[00m"
done
```

Comment: I've tested your solution but it is not working for me. For example the [[ "$DIR_CHECK" =~ "INCORRECT" ]]  trying to execute the result of of expression and report error.

Comment: oh. i see. the copy crapped something. i'll check this.

Comment: @ xx4h 
I think I got your idea. I'm going to implement it in _tcsh_ inside _foreach_ command.

Comment: Not whitespace safe.

Answer (score 0):

No, at least in the current implementations of ls. The maximum you can do is selecting colors depending on the file type (image, sound recording etc., based on file name mask), entry type (file, directory, socket etc.) and, partially, permissions (executable flags). You are not able to apply color for directory depending even on the files it contains, not saying about the *content* of those files.