# Coloring different sources for tail

Tags: command-line, colors, tail

I'm watching different logs by

```
tail -q -f /var/log/syslog -f /var/log/fail2ban.log -f /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

How can I have the output of each log colored differently?

Comment: See also [How to have tail -f show colored output](http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/8414/5923)

Comment: @MattBianco thanks, I'll have a look into `multitail` and the answers in this question

Comment: In addition to the great answers below, you may also want to check out http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/26313/colored-find-output which shows how to do much more with colorizing output files.

Answer (score 21, accepted):

Using GNU `grep` for the colouring:

```
color() { GREP_COLOR=$1 grep --color '.*'; }

(tail -qf /var/log/syslog | color 31 &
tail -qf /var/log/fail2ban.log | color 32 &
tail -qf /var/log/nginx/error.log | color 33)
```

Note that the first 2 are started in background. That means they won't be killed if you press <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd> (shell explicitly ignore SIGINT for asynchronous jobs).

To prevent that, you can do instead:

```
color() { GREP_COLOR=$1 grep --line-buffered --color=always '.*'; }

(tail -qf /var/log/syslog | color 31 &
tail -qf /var/log/fail2ban.log | color 32 &
tail -qf /var/log/nginx/error.log | color 33) | cat
```

That way, upon <kbd>Ctrl-C</kbd>, the last `tail+grep` and `cat` die (of the SIGINT) and the other two grep+tails will die of a SIGPIPE the next time they write something.

Or restore the SIGINT handler (won't work with all shells):

```
color() { GREP_COLOR=$1 grep --color '.*'; }

((trap - INT; tail -qf /var/log/syslog | color 31) &
(trap - INT; tail -qf /var/log/fail2ban.log | color 32) &
tail -qf /var/log/nginx/error.log | color 33)
```

You can also do it in the `color` function. That won't apply to `tail`, but `tail` will die of a SIGPIPE the next time it writes if `grep` dies.

```
color() (trap - INT; GREP_COLOR=$1 exec grep --color '.*')

(tail -qf /var/log/syslog | color 31 &
tail -qf /var/log/fail2ban.log | color 32 &
tail -qf /var/log/nginx/error.log | color 33)
```

Or make the whole tail+grep a function:

```
tailc() (trap - INT; export GREP_COLOR="$1"; shift; tail -qf -- "$@" |
   grep --color '.*')
tailc 31 /var/log/syslog &
tailc 32 /var/log/syslog &
tailc 33 /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

Or the whole thing:

```
tailc() (
  while [ "$#" -ge 2 ]; do
    (trap - INT; tail -f -- "$2" | GREP_COLOR=$1 grep --color '.*') &
    shift 2
  done
  wait
)

tailc 31 /var/log/syslog 32 /var/log/syslog 33 /var/log/nginx/error.log
```

Comment: When I put this into my "watch.sh" script, it returns to my console but messages get printed, see http://i.imgur.com/yaiBwMo.png

Comment: @Dan, see the edit

Comment: Thank you for your effort in writing this answer, I gone with the `tailc` function which worked best and looks most intuitive in the script.

Answer (score 4):

Someting like this worked for me:

```
(tail -f /var/log/syslog | awk -W interactive '{printf "\033[1;31m%s\033[0m\n", $0}' & \
tail -f /var/log/auth.log | awk -W interactive '{printf "\033[1;32m%s\033[0m\n", $0}' & \
tail -f /var/log/Xorg.0.log | awk -W interactive '{printf "\033[1;34m%s\033[0m\n", $0}')
```

Explanation:

- `tail -f file`: append data as file grows
- `awk -W interactive`: set `awk` to interactive mode
- `'{printf "\033[1;31m%s\033[0m\n", $0}'` print the output colorzized to the terminal.
- `\033[1;31m` means red
- `\033[1;32m` means green
- `\033[1;34m` means blue

Comment: `-W interactive` seems to be `mawk`-specific. (the way `mawk` buffers its input by default is also unique, and `-W interactive` would not be needed in other `awk` implementations).